# Changing Windows Time and Date Format

Tags: powershell

I'd like to automate preferences on a Windows machine for the date and time formats used throughout the OS.

What PowerShell commands can I use to automate this task of changing values?

- short date format
- short and long time format

These [options are buried deep in Control Panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4oV.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the settings you are looking for are located in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sLongDate
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sShortDate
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sTimeFormat
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sYearMonth
```

So,

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" 
                 -name sLongDate -value "<Whatever format you'd like>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Full example based on p.campbell's answer:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sCountry -Value "Germany";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sLongDate -Value "dddd, d. MMMM yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortDate -Value "dd.MM.yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortTime -Value "HH:mm";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sTimeFormat -Value "HH:mm:ss";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sYearMonth -Value "MMMM yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name iFirstDayOfWeek -Value 0;
```

To set the settings of the default user instead of the system, use `HKU:\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International`. For a specific user use `HKU:\(UserSID)\Control Panel\International`.

To get the SID of the current user, use

```
([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).User.Value
```

If you don't have `HKU:` mapped, use

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS
```

Comment: Very helpful, but you forgot `sShortTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on p.campbells's answer, but with all properties:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sCountry -Value "Germany";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sLongDate -Value "dddd, d. MMMM yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortDate -Value "dd.MM.yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortTime -Value "HH:mm";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sTimeFormat -Value "HH:mm:ss";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sYearMonth -Value "MMMM yyyy";
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name iFirstDayOfWeek -Value 0;
```

Comment: Why not just edit the existing answer to add the missing keys?